# Print multiple pages in C# from multiple child forms, in a single file

Tags: c#

I have a child form with a print button that prints out the content of the form in a nicely formatted page (some contact info). Here is the code of the method called by the Print event of that form:

```
 public void PrintContact(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
            // Create pen.
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

            // Create points that define line.

            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 8); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up
            Font titleFont = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

            float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

            int startX = 10;
            int startY = 10;
            int offset = 40;

            graphic.DrawString("BUSINESS" + ddlCompany.SelectedText, new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
            offset = offset + (int)fontHeight; //make the spacing consistent
            graphic.DrawString("Name: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbFirstName.Text + " " + tbMiddleName.Text + " " + tbLastName.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Phone: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbPhone.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Designation: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbDesignation.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Phone 2: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbPhone2.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Title: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbTitle.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Fax: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbFax.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Address: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbAddress.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Mobile: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbMobile.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("City: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbCity.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Phone 3: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbPhone3.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Prov/State: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbProv.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Email1: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbEmail1.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("ZIP: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbPostalCode.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Email 2: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbEmail2.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 30;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(startX, startY + offset), new Point(startX + 1000, startY + offset));
            offset += 30;

            //Notes Section
            graphic.DrawString("NOTES", new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY+offset);
            offset += 50;
            SizeF sf = graphic.MeasureString(tbNotes.Text,titleFont, 800);
            graphic.DrawString(tbNotes.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(new PointF(startX, startY + offset), sf));
            offset = offset + 100;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(startX, startY + offset), new Point(startX + 1000, startY + offset));
            offset += 30;

            //Home Section
            graphic.DrawString("HOME", new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset += 50;
            graphic.DrawString("Address: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbHomeStreet.Text + " " + tbMiddleName.Text + " " + tbLastName.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Phone: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbHomePhone.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("City: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbHomeCity.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Phone 2: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbHomePhone2.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Assistant: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbHomeState.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(70) + "Fax: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(80) + tbAssistantName.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Assistant Phone: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbAssistantPhone.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Assistant Email: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbAssistantEmail.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Anniversary: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbAnniversary.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Birthday: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + dateTimePicker2.Value, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Spouse: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbSpouse.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Children: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString(tbChildren1.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbChildren2.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString(tbChildren3.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbChildren4.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString(tbChildren5.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbChildren6.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString("Hobby: ", titleFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            graphic.DrawString("".PadRight(14) + tbHobby.Text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 30;


        }
```

In the parent form, I have a DataGridView with multiple rows and by double click of a row, the child form opens. In that same parent form, I have a button "print all" which will print all the details of the child forms. Basically, instead of opening the child form for each row, clicking print, and so on, the "print all" would print all the details in multiple pages.

I would like to reuse the code above in the parent form to print all. Here is the method I have made so far:

```
private void btnPrintListDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open the print dialog
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            printDialog.Document = printDocDetailed;
            printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

            //Get the document
            if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
            {

                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex > -1)
                {

                    foreach (DataGridView currentGridView in tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
                    {
                        printDocDetailed = new PrintDocument();

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in currentGridView.Rows)
                        {
                            EditContact contact = new EditContact(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                            printDocDetailed.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(contact.PrintContact);
                        }

                        printDocDetailed.Print();

                    }

                }

            }
```

This doesn't work as all the child forms content is printed on a single page, overlapping each other. I can move the "printDocDetailed.Print()" inside the foreach but that will print them all in separate files.

Is there a way to print all those child forms content to a single file with multiple pages, preferably by using existing code?

Comment: You have to alter your `printDocDetailed.Printpage` to handle `PrintEventArgs.HasMorePages`. This is more work than you may realize; consult [`PrintEventArgs.HasMorePages` dont work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939393/). Read the [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) docs; they have an example of printing multiple pages.

Comment: Also, fonts are unmanaged resources, and Brushes are cached. You should be instantiating these, once, in your constructor or `BeginPrint` and disposing them, once, when you finish printing.

Comment: thanks to both for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the matter by handling the print button event as usual:

```
private void btnPrintListDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open the print dialog
    PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
    printDialog.Document = printDocDetail;
    printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;

    //Get the document
    if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog() && tabControl.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {

        foreach (DataGridView currentGridView in tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
        {

            rows = currentGridView.Rows;
            page = 0;

            printDocDetail.DocumentName = "Contact List Detailed";
            printDocDetail.Print();

        }

    }
}
```

And copying the print event handler code to the same class and add class variable for page count:

```
   private void printDocDetail_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    // Create points that define line.
    Font font = new Font("Courier New", 8); //must use a mono spaced font as the spaces need to line up
    Font titleFont = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

    int startX = 10;
    int startY = 10;
    int offset = 40;

    DataGridViewRow row = rows.SharedRow(page);
    EditContact contact = new EditContact(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());

    // same code to print as initial question inserted here

    page++;

    e.HasMorePages = (page < rows.Count) ? true : false;

}
```

Works as desired